# Rotor spinning by hydropower

Tags: physics

I am trying to figure out how to spin a rotor by using the force of water.

Now I am not coming to a good result or even close...

Please explain how to make a rotor spin by the force of the water as in the video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RVlXncgtQus

Thanks in advance!